# Python Tkinter Listbox: fire off a function on change?

Tags: python, events, listbox, tkinter, listener

My problem is: when I click an option in a `Listbox`, I want a third party Text [area] to be updated with information based on the `Listbox`s selection. As far as I can tell though I can't see a way to harvest that event. I come from java and am used to registering listeners and the like, is there a way to do something similar here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `<<ListboxSelect>>`:

http://farmdev.com/src/secrets/decorator/tkinter/step3.html